# What happens to a dependency visa while we wait for a change of job work permit to be processed?

Tags: sweden, work-permit

We moved to Sweden from the UK about 9 months ago with my new job, who sponsored my work visa, and my wife has a dependancy visa. Unfortunately, I am being made redundant, and I am trying to make sure I understand our options.

I know that I will need to apply for a completely new permit so will need a job where the company will support that. Once I secure that job, I also understand that I will be able to start work while the new application is processed rather than having to wait.

What I can't work out is what happens with my wife's dependency visa. Will she be able to continue working while we wait for my permit to get processed as well, or will she lose the right to work until my new permit has actually been granted?